# Can I create indexes on multiple columns in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I heard indexes are good, can I create a clustered index on multiple columns, or can clustered index be created only on one column in SQL server 2012?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By Default PK Creates cluster index on tables so you can only one cluster index per table

Comment: You can create indexes on multiple columns in both clustered and non clustered indexes(in any version).

Comment: Ganesh_Devlekar yes you right. but myquestion is can i create culterindex with multiple columns same as like composite primary key

Comment: @PPRas'd you can, it will create composite primary key, it will not create Clustered index on multiple columns

Comment: You *can* do it - but whether you *should* do it is another question. The clustered index works best if it's **narrow, unique, stable** and preferably also ever-increasing (think: `INT IDENTITY`). The clustered index entry is also added into **ever single** non-clustered index on that table - so having a large, wide clustered index with lots of columns is usually **not a good idea**

Answer (score 0):

Composite Index: You can create index on Multiple Columns but up to 16 columns can be combined into a single composite index key. All the columns in a composite index key must be in the same table or view. The maximum allowable size of the combined index values is 900 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a composite clustered index which will include several columns in your index. But, it is going to affect your Insert/Update performance.

A simple clustered index would be as like

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Col1] ASC, [Col2] ASC, [COL3] ASC)
```

This means, you datarows are stored like-

```
Col1    Col2     Col3
1        1        1
1        1        2
1        2        3
2        5        2
2        6        5
3        2        1
3        5        2
```